# Error installing python "implicit" framework

Tags: python

I am trying to install the implicit package on Windows 10 and Python 2.7.15, using this command:

```
pip install implicit
```

There seems to be an error with implicit/bpr.cpp if I am not mistaken. Anyone knows what the problem is?

> implicit\bpr.cpp(1277) : fatal error C1003: error count exceeds 100; stopping compilation

This is the log I am getting:

```
    C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install implicit
Collecting implicit
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d9/0c/7f9f065cceab3c27b7207bbbc3127ff698f1dbaabc2e5f5ef92cb3a39a43/implicit-0.3.6.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from implicit) (1.11.2+mkl)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.16 in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from implicit) (0.18.1)
Requirement already satisfied: h5py in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from implicit) (2.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from implicit) (4.24.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from h5py->implicit) (1.10.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: implicit
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for implicit ... error
  Complete output from command c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\shiro\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-install-civoat\\implicit\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d c:\users\shiro\appdata\local\temp\pip-wheel-iv5suw --python-tag cp27:
  WARNING:root:The nvcc binary could not be located in your $PATH. Either add it to your path, or set $CUDAHOME to enable CUDA extensions
  Failed to find CUDA toolkit. Building without GPU acceleration.
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\implicit
  copying implicit\als.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\implicit
  copying implicit\approximate_als.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\implicit
  copying implicit\nearest_neighbours.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\implicit
  copying implicit\recommender_base.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\implicit
  copying implicit\utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\implicit
  copying implicit\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\implicit
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\implicit\cuda
  copying implicit\cuda\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\implicit\cuda
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\implicit\datasets
  copying implicit\datasets\lastfm.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\implicit\datasets
  copying implicit\datasets\million_song_dataset.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\implicit\datasets
  copying implicit\datasets\movielens.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\implicit\datasets
  copying implicit\datasets\sketchfab.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\implicit\datasets
  copying implicit\datasets\_download.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\implicit\datasets
  copying implicit\datasets\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\implicit\datasets
  running build_ext
  building 'implicit._als' extension
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\implicit
  C:\Users\shiro\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Ic:\python27\include -Ic:\python27\PC /Tpimplicit\_als.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\implicit\_als.obj /O2 /openmp
  _als.cpp
  C:\Users\shiro\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Include\xlocale(342) : warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc
  implicit\_als.cpp(3637) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'long' to 'char', possible loss of data
  implicit\_als.cpp(3919) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'long' to 'char', possible loss of data
  implicit\_als.cpp(4404) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  implicit\_als.cpp(4405) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  implicit\_als.cpp(4850) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
  implicit\_als.cpp(5568) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  implicit\_als.cpp(5569) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  implicit\_als.cpp(6732) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  implicit\_als.cpp(6733) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  implicit\_als.cpp(7178) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
  implicit\_als.cpp(7896) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  implicit\_als.cpp(7897) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  implicit\_als.cpp(9060) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  implicit\_als.cpp(9061) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  implicit\_als.cpp(9506) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
  implicit\_als.cpp(10224) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  implicit\_als.cpp(10225) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  implicit\_als.cpp(11678) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'long' to 'char', possible loss of data
  implicit\_als.cpp(11960) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'long' to 'char', possible loss of data
  implicit\_als.cpp(12468) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  implicit\_als.cpp(12469) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  implicit\_als.cpp(12854) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
  implicit\_als.cpp(12999) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
  implicit\_als.cpp(13040) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
  implicit\_als.cpp(13526) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  implicit\_als.cpp(13527) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  implicit\_als.cpp(14584) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  implicit\_als.cpp(14585) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  implicit\_als.cpp(14970) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
  implicit\_als.cpp(15115) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
  implicit\_als.cpp(15156) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
  implicit\_als.cpp(15642) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  implicit\_als.cpp(15643) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  implicit\_als.cpp(16700) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  implicit\_als.cpp(16701) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  implicit\_als.cpp(17086) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
  implicit\_als.cpp(17231) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
  implicit\_als.cpp(17272) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
  implicit\_als.cpp(17758) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  implicit\_als.cpp(17759) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  implicit\_als.cpp(19070) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'long' to 'char', possible loss of data
  implicit\_als.cpp(19352) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'long' to 'char', possible loss of data
  implicit\_als.cpp(19842) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  implicit\_als.cpp(19843) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  implicit\_als.cpp(19844) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  implicit\_als.cpp(20148) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
  implicit\_als.cpp(20652) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  implicit\_als.cpp(20653) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  implicit\_als.cpp(20654) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  implicit\_als.cpp(21462) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  implicit\_als.cpp(21463) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  implicit\_als.cpp(21464) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  implicit\_als.cpp(21768) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
  implicit\_als.cpp(22272) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  implicit\_als.cpp(22273) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  implicit\_als.cpp(22274) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  implicit\_als.cpp(23082) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  implicit\_als.cpp(23083) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  implicit\_als.cpp(23084) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  implicit\_als.cpp(23388) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
  implicit\_als.cpp(23892) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  implicit\_als.cpp(23893) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  implicit\_als.cpp(23894) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  C:\Users\shiro\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\link.exe /DLL /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LIBPATH:c:\python27\libs /LIBPATH:c:\python27\PCbuild\amd64 /LIBPATH:c:\python27\PC\VS9.0\amd64 /EXPORT:init_als build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\implicit\_als.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\implicit\_als.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\implicit\_als.lib /MANIFESTFILE:build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\implicit\_als.pyd.manifest
  _als.obj : warning LNK4197: export 'init_als' specified multiple times; using first specification
     Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\implicit\_als.lib and object build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\implicit\_als.exp
  C:\Users\shiro\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\WinSDK\Bin\x64\mt.exe -nologo -manifest build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\implicit\_als.pyd.manifest -outputresource:build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\implicit\_als.pyd;2
  building 'implicit._nearest_neighbours' extension
  C:\Users\shiro\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Iimplicit -Ic:\python27\include -Ic:\python27\PC /Tpimplicit\_nearest_neighbours.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\implicit\_nearest_neighbours.obj /O2 /openmp
  _nearest_neighbours.cpp
  C:\Users\shiro\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Include\xlocale(342) : warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc
  implicit\_nearest_neighbours.cpp(2867) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'long' to 'char', possible loss of data
  implicit\_nearest_neighbours.cpp(3187) : warning C4800: 'int' : forcing value to bool 'true' or 'false' (performance warning)
  implicit\_nearest_neighbours.cpp(3604) : warning C4267: '=' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  implicit\_nearest_neighbours.cpp(4027) : warning C4800: 'int' : forcing value to bool 'true' or 'false' (performance warning)
  implicit\_nearest_neighbours.cpp(4444) : warning C4267: '=' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  C:\Users\shiro\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\link.exe /DLL /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LIBPATH:c:\python27\libs /LIBPATH:c:\python27\PCbuild\amd64 /LIBPATH:c:\python27\PC\VS9.0\amd64 /EXPORT:init_nearest_neighbours build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\implicit\_nearest_neighbours.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\implicit\_nearest_neighbours.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\implicit\_nearest_neighbours.lib /MANIFESTFILE:build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\implicit\_nearest_neighbours.pyd.manifest
  _nearest_neighbours.obj : warning LNK4197: export 'init_nearest_neighbours' specified multiple times; using first specification
     Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\implicit\_nearest_neighbours.lib and object build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\implicit\_nearest_neighbours.exp
  C:\Users\shiro\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\WinSDK\Bin\x64\mt.exe -nologo -manifest build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\implicit\_nearest_neighbours.pyd.manifest -outputresource:build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\implicit\_nearest_neighbours.pyd;2
  building 'implicit.bpr' extension
  C:\Users\shiro\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Iimplicit -Ic:\python27\include -Ic:\python27\PC /Tpimplicit\bpr.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\implicit\bpr.obj /O2 /openmp
  bpr.cpp
  C:\Users\shiro\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Include\xlocale(342) : warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc
  implicit\bpr.cpp(954) : error C2039: 'mt19937' : is not a member of 'std'
  implicit\bpr.cpp(954) : error C2065: 'mt19937' : undeclared identifier
  implicit\bpr.cpp(955) : error C2039: 'uniform_int_distribution' : is not a member of 'std'
  implicit\bpr.cpp(955) : error C2065: 'uniform_int_distribution' : undeclared identifier
  implicit\bpr.cpp(955) : error C2062: type 'long' unexpected
  implicit\bpr.cpp(956) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
  implicit\bpr.cpp(966) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
  implicit\bpr.cpp(981) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
  implicit\bpr.cpp(991) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
  implicit\bpr.cpp(994) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1004) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1017) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1027) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1032) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1033) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1045) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1047) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1060) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1062) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1074) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1075) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1076) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1077) : error C2059: syntax error : ','
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1077) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1078) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before ')'
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1079) : error C2059: syntax error : ','
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1079) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1080) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before ')'
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1081) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before ')'
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1082) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1094) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1096) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1165) : error C2065: 'attr_name' : undeclared identifier
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1165) : error C2275: 'PyObject' : illegal use of this type as an expression
          c:\python27\include\object.h(108) : see declaration of 'PyObject'
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1165) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before ')'
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1178) : error C2065: 'kw_name' : undeclared identifier
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1178) : error C2275: 'PyObject' : illegal use of this type as an expression
          c:\python27\include\object.h(108) : see declaration of 'PyObject'
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1178) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before ')'
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1181) : error C2065: 'argnames' : undeclared identifier
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1181) : error C2059: syntax error : ']'
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1182) : error C2065: 'kwds2' : undeclared identifier
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1182) : error C2275: 'PyObject' : illegal use of this type as an expression
          c:\python27\include\object.h(108) : see declaration of 'PyObject'
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1182) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ',' before identifier 'values'
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1182) : error C2065: 'values' : undeclared identifier
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1182) : error C2059: syntax error : ']'
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1183) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ',' before identifier 'function_name'
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1183) : error C2065: 'function_name' : undeclared identifier
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1183) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before ')'
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1190) : error C2065: 'arg' : undeclared identifier
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1190) : error C2275: 'PyObject' : illegal use of this type as an expression
          c:\python27\include\object.h(108) : see declaration of 'PyObject'
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1190) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ',' before identifier 'kw'
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1190) : error C2065: 'kw' : undeclared identifier
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1190) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before ')'
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1213) : error C2065: 'type' : undeclared identifier
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1213) : error C2275: 'PyObject' : illegal use of this type as an expression
          c:\python27\include\object.h(108) : see declaration of 'PyObject'
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1213) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ',' before identifier 'value'
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1213) : error C2065: 'value' : undeclared identifier
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1213) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ',' before identifier 'tb'
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1213) : error C2065: 'tb' : undeclared identifier
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1213) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before ')'
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1214) : error C2065: 'type' : undeclared identifier
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1214) : error C2275: 'PyObject' : illegal use of this type as an expression
          c:\python27\include\object.h(108) : see declaration of 'PyObject'
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1214) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ',' before identifier 'value'
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1214) : error C2065: 'value' : undeclared identifier
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1214) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ',' before identifier 'tb'
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1214) : error C2065: 'tb' : undeclared identifier
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1214) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before ')'
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1232) : error C2065: 'value' : undeclared identifier
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1232) : error C2275: 'PyObject' : illegal use of this type as an expression
          c:\python27\include\object.h(108) : see declaration of 'PyObject'
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1232) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ',' before identifier 'tb'
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1232) : error C2065: 'tb' : undeclared identifier
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1232) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ',' before identifier 'cause'
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1232) : error C2065: 'cause' : undeclared identifier
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1232) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before ')'
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1246) : error C2065: 'args' : undeclared identifier
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1246) : error C2275: 'PyObject' : illegal use of this type as an expression
          c:\python27\include\object.h(108) : see declaration of 'PyObject'
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1246) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ',' before identifier 'nargs'
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1246) : error C2065: 'nargs' : undeclared identifier
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1246) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ',' before identifier 'kwargs'
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1246) : error C2065: 'kwargs' : undeclared identifier
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1246) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before ')'
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1254) : error C2065: 'arg' : undeclared identifier
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1254) : error C2275: 'PyObject' : illegal use of this type as an expression
          c:\python27\include\object.h(108) : see declaration of 'PyObject'
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1254) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before ')'
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1258) : error C2065: 'arg' : undeclared identifier
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1258) : error C2275: 'PyObject' : illegal use of this type as an expression
          c:\python27\include\object.h(108) : see declaration of 'PyObject'
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1258) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before ')'
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1269) : error C2065: 'op2' : undeclared identifier
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1269) : error C2275: 'PyObject' : illegal use of this type as an expression
          c:\python27\include\object.h(108) : see declaration of 'PyObject'
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1269) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ',' before identifier 'intval'
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1269) : error C2065: 'intval' : undeclared identifier
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1269) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ',' before identifier 'inplace'
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1269) : error C2065: 'inplace' : undeclared identifier
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1269) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before ')'
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1277) : error C2065: 'op2' : undeclared identifier
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1277) : error C2275: 'PyObject' : illegal use of this type as an expression
          c:\python27\include\object.h(108) : see declaration of 'PyObject'
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1277) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ',' before identifier 'intval'
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1277) : error C2065: 'intval' : undeclared identifier
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1277) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ',' before identifier 'inplace'
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1277) : error C2065: 'inplace' : undeclared identifier
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1277) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before ')'
  implicit\bpr.cpp(1277) : fatal error C1003: error count exceeds 100; stopping compilation
  error: command 'C:\\Users\\shiro\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for implicit
  Running setup.py clean for implicit
Failed to build implicit
Installing collected packages: implicit
  Running setup.py install for implicit ... error
  [...]
```

Comment: looks to me like the code requires the c++11 random library. Possible reasons it fails. Maybe wrong VS version or the build is using in appropriate flags to specify c++ version?

Comment: @PaulRooney The author of the library also says that this is probably the issue. But what's the fix? I am using Visual C++ 9.0 and Python 2.7.15. If you look [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers#Which_Microsoft_Visual_C.2B-.2B-_compiler_to_use_with_a_specific_Python_version_.3F) it says that I am supposed to use Version 9.0 for Python 2.7. Right?

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure. Version 9 is also known as VS 2008, which I'm guessing has no c++ 11 support. So seems like the way to fix it is to take the plunge and go with an appropriate version of python 3. The library is making 2.7 incompatible by virtue of using c++ features that VS2008 doesn't support.

Comment: if you using anaconda try `conda install -c conda-forge implicit`